# How to cancel queue_delayed_work immediately?

Tags: linux-device-driver

In my driver will call queue_delayed_work and do things,

```
queue_delayed_work(queue, work, 60000);
```

then stop this queue after some conditions:

```
cancel_delayed_work_sync(work);
flush_delayed_work(work);
flush_workqueue(queue);
```

And the worker function:

```
static void worker(struct work_struct *work) {
    printk("this is worker function!\n");
    ...
    queue_delayed_work(queue, work, 60000);
}
```

But I find that worker function still can be triggered after I do stop the work queue(cancel and flush)
How did it happen and how should I avoid it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to cancel a work entry submitted to the shared queue, you may use cancel_delayed_work.

If you want to flush the shared workqueue requires a separate function:

```
void flush_scheduled_work(void)
```